# HDividedBox is not completely dragging to the left side for VGroup Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I observed when we use VGroup in the HDividedBox dragging is not completely moving to the left side.The components in the VGroup are still appearing when we drag the hdivider completely.But when we use VBox in the HDividedBox dragging is working perfectly.
Here is sample code

`<mx:HDividedBox id="hdivbox" width="100%" height="100%" liveDragging="true">

        <s:VGroup  width="50%" height="100%" >
               <s:ComboBox/>
               <s:ComboBox/>
            </s:VGroup>
            <s:VGroup  width="50%" height="100%" >
              <s:Panel width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </s:VGroup>
</mx:HDividedBox>`

Now when we drag divider completely to the left side first combobox is visible but when i replace the same code with VBox dragging is working fine. Can any one help me on how to fix this without using VBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time to understand why this happens, but it was really interesting, so thank you for a question. If you just need to fix it use `clipAndEnableScrolling="true"`in first VGroup.

The problem is that in `VBox`property [clipContent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/GroupBase.html#clipAndEnableScrolling) defaults to true, but in `VGroup`almost the same property [clipAndEnableScrolling](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Container.html#clipContent) dafaults to false. This cause this different behavior.

Comment: Wow Thanks Art thank u so much by giving the property clipAndEnableScrolling="true" its perfectly working.